# Custom Inputs on Identity server 3 login

Tags: identityserver3

Is it possible to customize the login page / authentication logic within identity server in order to allow a user to authenticate without there username and password but instead using a customer number and say a postcode.

I have implemented a custom view service that uses the username and password properties but I was hoping on a slightly better solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can customize it.

You would have to create your own implementation of `IUserService` to validate whatever values you want and `IViewService` to render and submit the desired markup.

See more here:

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/userService.html
https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/customViewService.html

Comment: I have read the documentation and have already implemented a custom UserService that authenticates the user but this is always passed LocalAuthenticationContext which ties the user to specify a Username and Password. At the moment I have created a custom view service that passes 2 hidden fields for username and password as this is always validated. I then inside the AuthenticateLocalAsync method get additional post form values from the request. I though this was a little messy and didn't know whether I had missed any obvious areas of abstraction to implement required functionality?

Comment: Yes, I think that is the way you have to do it unfortunately.